# Error when calling dependency of one method of another class into other class in TestNG automation

Tags: testing, automation, testng

I want to add dependency of one test method from class A to another testMethod in class B. 
Whenever I am running method "testTwo()" from class B I am getting error as 
"method B.testTwo() depends on nonexistent group A.Group1" , my class structure is as below .

```
public class A
{
  @Test(groups={"A.Group1"})
   public void testOne(){}
}
public class B
{
  @Test(dependsOnGroups={"A.Group1"})
   public void testTwo(){}
}
```

Can anyone please guide here ?,

also My test.xml looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="TEST-AUTOMATION" thread-count="1"
        preserve-order="true" data-provider-thread-count="1">

    <test name="TESTS">
        <classes>
            <class name="A"/>
            <class name="B"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Comment: i tried the same, no issue working fine. Only diff is is used total class name in TestNF.xml file like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TEST-AUTOMATION" thread-count="1"
        preserve-order="true" data-provider-thread-count="1">
     <test name="TESTS">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.letsDo.A"/>
      <class name="com.letsDo.B"/>

    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

Comment: Thanks Murali for help., but I tried same by adding full package name to class as you mentioned but still failing with error as "method B.testTwo() depends on nonexistent group A.Group1"

Comment: try once removing un-necessary imports and cleaning project

Comment: Thank but I tried this as well but no luck, still same issue .. Dont know why it is not taking dependency form other class :(

Comment: are you running class? run testng.xml

Comment: No, I am running a particular test case , Do i need to run a class ?

Comment: No run form testing.xml. it will work. On running class I also got issue